Run many wildcard rules one-after-the-other sequentially rather than in parallel?
This may sound like a weird requirement, but I have a workflow that runs rules on > 150k files. Most of them can run in parallel and hence I use wildcards.
Now I'm at a point in the workflow where I need to run all files past a REST API with rate limits.
In order to avoid breaking those limits, I'd like to query the API on all files one after the other.
To do this, I have created a checkpoint which takes as input all wildcarded files as a list and queries the REST API:
This is the checkpoint code as it is now:
def get_all_files(wildcards):
    split_dir = checkpoints.split.get(**wildcards).output['output_dir']
    split_files = glob_wildcards(
        os.path.join(split_dir,'{filename}.json')
    ).filename
    return expand('resources/split-files/{filename}.json', filename=split_files)


checkpoint query_api:
    input:
        input_files=get_all_files
    output:
        output_dir=directory("resources/enriched-files")
    resources:
        mem='24GB',
        runtime='21d',
    script:
        "scripts/query_api.py"

This works fine, but I expect the job to run > 2 weeks, in which many bad things could happen (the cluster isn't very stable).
In order to avoid having to restart the job many times, I was wondering if it's possible to create one job per input file, but instead of running them in parallel, run them one after the other (sequentially) to a) avoid hitting rate limits, but b) also to be able to restart the workflow at any given time wihout having to query the API for all files again.
Is this something you can do with Snakemake?

Not sure this is what you need, but maybe it is worth having a look at job groups: https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/grouping.html I used this to reduce the number of jobs submitted to a cluster: a batch of snakemake jobs are grouped to be submitted as one cluster job. I suppose they run in sequence, then.

You can do just this, and hopefully avoid the need for checkpoints in your code (which are powerful but also tricky).
What you are looking for is handled by resources in Snakemake. Your query_api rule already has mem and runtime resources but you can add a third:
api_call=1
and then on the command line, or in your profile, say --resources api_call=1 (or --resources api_call=2 if you think you can get away with two jobs running at once.)
See:
https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#snakefiles-resources
Note that Snakemake considers api_call to be a global resource (unless you declare otherwise) but mem is a local resource. This makes a difference when jobs are run on a cluster but for local execution they are treated the same.
If you want to throttle API calls further the best thing is just to add a short sleep after the API query.

Thanks! I don't think I understand resources well enough yet, and couldn't find documentation for an api_calls resource (only a mention at the page you link to), nor a string api_call in the snakemake repo. Is this a custom resource? If so, how can I track it in my code?

Ah, I read again and think I understand how this works now via the combination of declaring the required resources and the assignment of resources via profile or CLI.
